# OR MOSFET circuit with considerable current consumption

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, low-power

I'm using the MOSFET circuit presented below to switch the power supply in the PCB (low power). The problem is the current consumption during the ON state of P1, which is 0.5mA to keep-on the pmos (The current nmos drains is controlled by the resistor R). However, due to the noise levels, I'm not able to increase the value of that resistor in order to decrease the current drain (I tried experimentally other values such 15k, 20k, ...). I began to design a circuit to disconnect the pull-up using PNP when PMOS is turned on, but the circuit became complex and possibly more current consuming. Maybe there is a clever way to do it.

Resuming the circuit functioning: S1 and S2 signals can be used to drive the P1 PMOS. When S1 or S2 are high, the PMOS gate is set to 0V, and the PMOS turn on. When S1 and S2 are both low, 5V appears at the PMOS gate trough R pull-up.

[image: OR circuit]

Comment: *When S1 or S2 are both high* <-- either?

Comment: yes, @Rahmany.  The current that pass trough R e and nmos drain is 0.5mA,  for a low power design and comparatively to other circuits in the same board is considerable high.

Comment: @Andy aka, the S1 is high when a push button is ON and S2 is commanded by a MCU.

Comment: "due to the noise levels, I'm not able to increase the value of that resistor" Seems hard to believe. What's causing the noise? Is it turning on P1 directly or turning on N1 or N2 and then causing the problem by turning P1 on? Try a capacitor across the 10k resistor.

Comment: Where is the noise you are talking about here? What is the Vth of the P1 used here? DO you really need 5V if not, try having the voltage divider circuit through NMOSs' and reduce the currents.

Comment: Depending on how much gate charge P1 requires and how quickly you need to switch it between states, you could just use a 5 V CMOS OR gate instead of building the OR circuit from discretes. For example 74LVC1G32.

Comment: You could add a capacitor (10 to 100 nF) parallel to R and increase R to 100 kohm or even more. This slows down the switching time of the P-FET but cancels the noise at the gate.

Comment: Hi @ThePhoton, Initially, I used an OR logic gate to simplify the circuit. The or gate, on the other hand, requires a voltage supply and is always powered on ( const. current consuming).

Comment: Something like a 74HC32 would take no more than 2uA if it wasn't driving an output. Much less than your 10k resistor.

Comment: @bmalbusca you could power it from the 5 V input, same as your circuit. And 74LVC1G32 takes only 10 uA in either 0 or 1 output state,  so unless your application hardly ever delivers power to the load, it will be much more efficient than your existing solution.

Comment: Thank you @Finbarr and ThePhoton, these values are indeed close to the leakage currents of the mosfets I'm using.

Comment: @ThePhoton and Finbarr, write your answer to give you the points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the gate of P1 to be low, if either S1 or S2 are high. That's the behaviour of a NOR gate:

| S1 | S2 | G |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

So, if you want no quiescent current to flow in *any* state, you could implement the classic static CMOS NOR gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faih9p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Current drawn by the gate:

[image]

P1 acts as an inverting stage, so \$V_{OUT}\$ becomes S1 ***OR*** S2. Also, ignore the voltage offsets, which are artificial to stack the graphs vertically; the actual signals are all 0V or 5V.

R1 is there to limit shoot-through current, but if your MOSFETs are small signal types, and you don't mind a few dozen milliamps flowing for a few nanoseconds at output transitions, you could omit R1. In any case, make sure you decouple the power supply adequately to provide those transient currents.

Alternatively, use a prepackaged NOR gate, like the [74HC1G02](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT1G02.pdf), [4001](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/schs015c/schs015c.pdf) or [74HC02](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/schs125d/schs125d.pdf):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZtOEQ.png)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could use any 5V CMOS buffer, say CD4050, 74HC08, etc.:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2nJ1h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The key idea is to filter 5V using a low-pass filter, with C1 directly across the supply pins of the buffer.

If your inputs are 3.3V level, and the buffer is a 74HCT type, then the mosfets are unnecessary:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3okZg.png)</sup>

Comment: A question about the second schmatic: If only one input is active, the output shoot through current of 4 mA will drain C1 until fed by the input protection diode. The driving MCU output now feeds the output fight and I expect around 1.4 V at the combined outputs. This might indeed turn on M2, but is this the intended kind of operation? In this situation >200 uA passes R3.